# How to superscript a registered trademark in Sphinx/RestructuredText?

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

How can I superscript the ® symbol in Sphinx/RestructuredText?

This does not work, I get a superscripted |reg| instead.

```
bigNameBrand\ :sup:`|reg|`
```

Comment: Is "bigNameBrand\ :sup:`®`" not an option for you?

Comment: oog... I really would like to stay with ASCII source files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a workaround by creating custom roles. Grr. I shouldn't have to do this.

in conf.py:

```
def supsub_role(name, rawtext, text, lineno, inliner, options={}, content=[]):
    node = docutils.nodes.superscript()
    node2 = docutils.nodes.substitution_reference(refname=text)
    node += [node2]
    return [node],[]

def setup(app):
    app.add_role('supsub', supsub_role)
```

and then:

```
.. |regsup| replace:: :supsub:`reg`
```

then you can use `|regsup|` to get the superscript registered trademark.